# EC2 instance in us-gov-west-1 getting 'The security token included in the request is invalid'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have an `m5a.large` EC2 instance (amazon linux 2) in `us-gov-west-1`, with an IAM role attached to the instance.

While ssh'd to the instance I can use the AWS cli (eg `aws s3 ls`) without any issue, i.e. it picks up the credentials from instance metadata.

I have the cloudwatch logs agent installed and running, but no logs are getting sent to cloudwatch.

inside `/var/log/awslogs.log`, I'm getting the following error.

```
2019-09-06 19:03:50,358 - cwlogs.push.publisher - WARNING - 11150 - Thread-17 - Caught exception: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
2019-09-06 19:03:50,358 - cwlogs.threads - ERROR - 11150 - Thread-17 - Exception caught in <EventBatchPublisher(Thread-17, started daemon 140468490651392)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/threads.py", line 58, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 1403, in _run
    self._publish_event_batch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 1210, in _publish_event_batch
    self.sequence_token = self._put_log_events(self.event_batch)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cwlogs/push.py", line 1248, in _put_log_events
    response = self.logs_service.put_log_events(**params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
UnrecognizedClientException: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the PutLogEvents operation: The security token included in the request is invalid
```

Weird. I check the instance metadata and everything seems okay

```
$ date 
Fri Sep  6 19:06:40 UTC 2019
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/my-role-name
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2019-09-06T18:19:25Z",
  "Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
  "AccessKeyId" : "redacted",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "redacted",
  "Token" : "redacted",
  "Expiration" : "2019-09-07T00:55:24Z"
}
```

Anything else I should be checking to better understand why AWS thinks I have an invalid security token?

Comment: In case it's related: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=218562. Might want to add --debug to awslogs-agent-launcher.sh to see if it provides more details.

Comment: The CloudWatch Agent is probably running as a different user, which might have local credentials defined within that user's home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my issue.

When installing awslogs via yum (`yum install awslogs`), it creates a directory in `/etc/awslogs`, with a config file called `awscli.conf`

The default config in that file is (as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html))

```
[plugins]
cwlogs = cwlogs
[default]
region = us-east-1
```

By updating that region to `us-gov-west-1`, the logs are shipped to cloudwatch.

So my updated config for `/etc/awslogs/awscli.conf` ended up being

```
[plugins]
cwlogs = cwlogs
[default]
region = us-gov-west-1
```